# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 250, 250, 3), found shape=(None, None, 250, 250, 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I have this error and i couldn't solve it. the error is

> "ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model" is incompatible with the layer:
> expected shape=(None, 250, 250, 3), found shape=(None, None, 250, 250,
> 3)"

The first thing i did is to resize my dataset to (250,250) by using (train.map) and (val.map) then i wrote the following lines as it is shown in the pic:

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECnLw.jpg)
I tried to change the input size to another sizes but i didn't work

Comment: You probably batched it twice.

Comment: Please don't post images of errors, code, logs, or other text. We also need a better problem description than "didn't work". See [ask].